# how to set search result page as a landing page?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I want to show all products and the filter attributes on landing page. How to configure Magento to show search result?

Comment: what do you mean search results as a landing page?

Answer (score 0):

**First, you'll want to set up a landing page** with your products and filter attributes.  Let's say you've created that page, and it's located here: http://www.awesomestore.com/landing-page1.htm

**Then, if you have a specific search term, such as "xyz" you can go into the search terms system and redirect any time someone searches for "xyz" to the correct landing page:**
[image: Search System - Create Landing Page]